# Am I using return correctly?

Tags: apex

Ok, this is a simplified version of my code that searches for accounts or leads to attach to new cases. If the case comes in with no account or lead, it is simple, search query for both, attach what is found. However, if the case comes in and has one or the other, it is a little more tricky. Using the account as example: Account comes in attached, search lead by available account emails, we have several on the account object, this example only shows 2 for clarity sake. What I am trying to make sure is correct, is that once it finds an email in one of the If statements and makes the upsert, it then exits the class completely. I am not 100% sure it is? Note, I am NOT using an else if because it is possible to find one email related to account that is not on a lead and vice versa, I need to search them in the order of importance I have them until one is found. Thank you for time!!!
Code:

```
//trigger searching for leads to attach if an account is found OR
//accounts to attach if lead is found on cases object

trigger AttachCaseByEmail on Case (after insert) {

    for (Case ca : Trigger.new){

        Case c = [SELECT Id, Account.PersonEmail, Account.Alt_Email_1__c, Applicant_Name__r.Email, Applicant_Name__r.Alt_Email_1__c, FROM Case Where Case.Id = :ca.Id];

        //null check, only query for account if account is null
        if(c.AccountId == null){
            //only do supplied email query if applicant is null as well, this if is inside account null to clear both applicant and lead search in this statement
            //this if only gets triggered if both applicant and account were null, search and then exit, nothing more to go off for searching
            if(c.Applicant_Name__c == null){
                //account search
                list<account> acc = [SELECT Id From Account Where Alt_Email_1__c = :c.SuppliedEmail OR PersonEmail = :c.SuppliedEmail Limit 1];
                if(acc.size()>0){
                    for(Account a :acc){
                        c.AccountId = a.Id;
                    }
                }
                //applicant search
                list<lead> lead = [SELECT Id From Lead Where (Email = :c.account.PersonEmail OR Alt_Email_1__c = :c.SuppliedEmail) AND IsConverted = false Limit 1];               
                if (lead.size()>0){
                    for (Lead l :lead){
                        c.Applicant_Name__c = l.Id;
                    }
                }
                //exit because both were null to begin with, query is done
                upsert c;
                return;
            }
            //if applicant was not null, then search for account off of applicant email, regardless if account is found exit because lead is already attached
            else{
                //if lead is attached, search by email for a related account by lead emails
                // using only if statements and not else if because email may not be found on only the first email searched, return if it is found
                if(c.Applicant_Name__r.Email != null){
                    list<account> acc = [SELECT Id From Account Where PersonEmail = :c.Applicant_Name__r.Email OR Alt_Email_1__c = :c.Applicant_Name__r.Email Limit 1];
                    if(acc.size()>0){
                        for(Account a :acc){
                            c.AccountId = a.Id;
                            upsert c;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(c.Applicant_Name__r.Alt_Email_1__c != null){
                    list<account> acc = [SELECT Id From Account Where PersonEmail = :c.Applicant_Name__r.Alt_Email_1__c OR Alt_Email_1__c = :c.Applicant_Name__r.Alt_Email_1__c Limit 1];
                    if(acc.size()>0){
                        for(Account a :acc){
                            c.AccountId = a.Id;
                            upsert c;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //exit out because a lead is attached already, even if account was not found
                return;
            }
        }
        else{
            system.debug('in account else, found account: ' + c.Account.UF_Email__c);
            //if account is attached, search by account email for a related lead, if one is not found, exit. 
            if(c.Account.PersonEmail != null){
                list<lead> lead = [SELECT Id From Lead Where (Email = :c.Account.PersonEmail OR Alt_Email_1__c = :c.Account.PersonEmail) AND IsConverted = false Limit 1];
                if (lead.size()>0){
                    for (Lead l :lead){
                        c.Applicant_Name__c = l.Id;
                        upsert c;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(c.Account.Alt_Email_1__c != null){
                list<lead> lead = [SELECT Id From Lead Where (Email = :c.Account.Alt_Email_1__c OR Alt_Email_1__c = :c.Account.Alt_Email_1__c) AND IsConverted = false Limit 1];
                if (lead.size()>0){
                    for (Lead l :lead){
                        c.Applicant_Name__c = l.Id;
                        upsert c;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the logic you are applying, you want to use a `continue` statement rather than `return` to continue on to the next iteration in your loop. The way you have it written, the first successful execution block will terminate all processing. What this means is, if you insert 100 `Case` records, and the first one hits a `return` statement, the other 99 are not processed by your trigger.

Whether it's "right" or not, you are not following best practice here, which is to *move your logic out of the trigger body*. The most straightforward way to do so is to move the code to a `static` method in a service layer. I would also consider proliferation of long `if` and `else` blocks to be an anti-pattern. And of course you need to bulkify your code by **removing your queries and database operations from loops**. This last is one of the most important concepts in `Apex`.

Another note, when you are transforming data on the trigger object, generally it is best practice to use a `before` trigger, which avoids hitting the database twice to perform a single operation. Unless you have `after` triggers creating the data you are looking for, move the logic to a `before` trigger and remove all `upsert` statements. If you must have it in an `after` trigger, use `update`. The fact you're in the `insert` trigger tells you they have been created already.

```
public with sharing class CaseServices
{
    public static void someAction(List<Case> newRecords)
    {
        // Pass in trigger.new
        // Queries should happen here
        for (Case record : newRecords) someAction(record);
        // Database operations should happen here
        // if they are, in fact, necessary
    }
    static void someAction(Case record)
    {
        // No SOQL or DML in this method!!!
        if (/*condition 1*/)
        {
            // do stuff
            return;
        }
        if (/*condition2*/)
        {
            // do stuff
            return;
        }
        // do stuff
        return;
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Designing the Qualify & Execute Logic in Triggers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121844/designing-the-qualify-execute-logic-in-triggers). The pattern I describe there may be useful to you as well. Try to filter all records that match a criteria, then apply the corresponding action. If you approach the problem in this way, you can write methods that each do one thing that is easy to comprehend (and test).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip on moving it out of trigger. I think it is doing what I want it to do then. I DONT want it to continue to the next if statement if it finds a lead or account, instead I want it to exit all executions completely if it makes it to one of the returns. Is that what it is doing, leaving the program completely at the return?

Comment: What is the proper method to get it to exit out then and go onto another record in the for statement without going through all my if statements. The first query to find an email matching another record should win upsert and be done.

Comment: @NicMcBride As I state in the (now) first sentence, you want to use `continue`. But this logic is not structured in a very Salesforce friendly way. You need to approach it from a collections perspective to be effective.

Comment: I hear you about it not being friendly from a collections standpoint, that is why I need to make sure it is not entering all of these if statements. Ideally it only enters one statement and is done on our primary email, however, I have to search each email on the account to every possible email field on the lead OR vice versa. First one found should be the primary, and if it does not find that one, then and only then will it do another SOQL, that is my intent at least. Is it possible to do a query where one field has a winner? like so - continued in next message....

Comment: SELECT Id From Account Where (PersonEmail = :c.Applicant_Name__r.Email OR PersonEmail = :c.Applicant_Name__r.Alt_Email_1__c)OR (Alt_Email_1__c = :c.Applicant_Name__r.Email OR Alt_Email_1__c = c.Applicant_Name__r.Alt_Email_1__c) Limit 1];

Comment: I would need the email to win and populate the account. I have not been able to figure out a cleaner way to do it from what I have done. If you have any tips, I am all ears. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, hate to be that guy, however, I am hitting one wall after another. I actually moved it out of the before insert and to an after insert because I was not able to pull back the related fields otherwise I.E. the Email on account will not bring the email back even if it had one: system.debug(Account email: '+ c.Account.PersonEmail); would be null in other words, even when confirmed not. So to get that I had to query, and it didn't have the ID on the case to query, until it was inserted. Is there another way to approach this to get the relationship that I am missing?